# Mongoose error for an React component not tided to Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have the following component in my Next.js app:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { fullStar, halfStar } from "@/public/icons/";

export default function Stars({ count }: { count: number }) {
    if (Number.isInteger(count)) {
        return (
            <div className="stars">
                {Array.from({ length: count }, () => (
                    <Image src={fullStar} alt={`${count} stars`} height={40} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }

    const stars = Math.floor(count)

    return (
        <div className="stars">
            {Array.from({ length: stars }, () => (
                <Image src={fullStar} alt={`${stars} and a`} height={40} />
            ))}
            <Image src={halfStar} alt="half stars" height={40}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This embedded into this portion of the same app:

```
"use client";

import * as Dialog from "@radix-ui/react-dialog";
import "./components.scss";
import { useRef, } from "react";
import useFetch from "@/hooks/useFetch";
import HTTPMethod from "http-method-enum";
import { CreateRating } from ".";

export default async function CreateReview({
    user,
    type,
    currentUser,
    isExistingReview,
}: {
    user: any;
    type: string;
    currentUser: any;
    isExistingReview: boolean;
}) {
    const titleRef = useRef("");
    const starsRef = useRef("1");
    const textRef = useRef("");

    const [data, error, loading, sendFetch] = useFetch();
    
    if (isExistingReview) {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>You&apos;ve already written a review for this user</h1>
            </>
        );
    }
    
    if (loading) {
        return (
            <Dialog.Root>
                <Dialog.Trigger asChild>
                    <button className="standard-clr-btn">Write a review</button>
                </Dialog.Trigger>
                <Dialog.Portal>
                    <Dialog.Overlay className="DialogOverlay" />
                    <Dialog.Content className="DialogContent standard-dialog">
                        loading
                    </Dialog.Content>
                </Dialog.Portal>
            </Dialog.Root>
        );
    }

    if (error) {
        return (
            <Dialog.Root>
                <Dialog.Trigger asChild>
                    <button className="standard-clr-btn">Write a review</button>
                </Dialog.Trigger>
                <Dialog.Portal>
                    <Dialog.Overlay className="DialogOverlay" />
                    <Dialog.Content className="DialogContent standard-dialog">
                        {data?.message || "Something went wrong"}
                    </Dialog.Content>
                </Dialog.Portal>
            </Dialog.Root>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Dialog.Root>
            <Dialog.Trigger asChild>
                <button className="standard-clr-btn">Write a review</button>
            </Dialog.Trigger>
            <Dialog.Portal>
                <Dialog.Overlay className="DialogOverlay" />
                <Dialog.Content className="DialogContent standard-dialog">
                    <Dialog.Title className="DialogTitle">Write a review...</Dialog.Title>
                    <Dialog.Description className="DialogDescription">
                        Write a review for {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
                        
                    </Dialog.Description>
                    <form
                        onSubmit={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            sendFetch("/api/reviews/add", HTTPMethod.POST, {
                                title: titleRef.current.value,
                                stars: parseInt(starsRef.current.value),
                                text: textRef.current.value,
                                type: type,
                                author: currentUser._id,
                                recipient: user._id
                            });
                        }}
                    >
                        <CreateRating count={5}/>
                        
                        <input
                            className="standard-input"
                            name="title"
                            ref={titleRef}
                            placeholder="title"
                        />
                        <input
                            className="standard-input"
                            name="stars"
                            ref={starsRef}
                            placeholder="stars"
                        />
                        <textarea name="review" ref={textRef} placeholder="text"></textarea>
                        <button
                            className="standard-clr-btn"
                            aria-label="Send"
                            type="submit"
                        >
                            Publish
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <Dialog.Close asChild>
                        <button className="IconButton" aria-label="Close">
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </Dialog.Close>
                </Dialog.Content>
            </Dialog.Portal>
        </Dialog.Root>
    );
}
```

When I do this I get an error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Ct` is not a valid type at path `author`. See bit.ly/mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.
Source

mongo/Review.ts (3:21) @ <unknown>

  1 | import mongoose from "mongoose";
  2 | 
> 3 | const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    |                     ^
  4 |   title: {
  5 |       type: String,
  6 |       required: true,
```

Removing `CreateReview` fixes everything. What's happening here?

Review Schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    stars: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    isReviewOnCustomer: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User",
    },
    recipient: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User",
    },
    comments: [{
        type: {
            text: {
                type: String,
            },
            author: {
                type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User",
            },
        },
        required: false,
    }],
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: () => Date.now(),
    },
    updatedAt: Date,
});

export default mongoose.models.Review || mongoose.model("Review", ReviewSchema);
```

All `createReview` does is return several `Image` components. Am I missing something here? Is it a bug in Mongoose or am I doing something wrong? The problem is likely in `createReview`.

Comment: please share your ReviewSchema definition.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that the author field has an invalid type configuration. In your Review schema, you have defined the author fields type as mongoose.Types.ObjectId. This could be causing the error. Try the following,

```js
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "User",
},
recipient: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "User",
},
comments: [{
    type: {
        text: {
            type: String,
        },
        author: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    },
    required: false,
}],
```

Also check on the frontend if the currentUser._id and user._id are strings. If so then try the following,

```js
sendFetch("/api/reviews/add", HTTPMethod.POST, {
    title: titleRef.current.value,
    stars: parseInt(starsRef.current.value),
    text: textRef.current.value,
    type: type,
    author: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(currentUser._id), // Convert currentUser._id to ObjectId 
    recipient: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id), // Convert user._id to ObjectId 
})
```

Comment: Now I'm getting error :```TypeError: can't access property "Review", mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default().models is undefined````

Comment: Try restarting the server. Please add code related to  Mongoose iinitialization and connection with your question. Check if your backend is establishing a connection before trying to save Review to db. You can add your backend code with your question too. Sorry, the error is not saying much and could be happening for many different reasons. But my bet is, it has to do with db connection or how you are attempting to save Review to the db.